# filtering not nulls and blanks in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

i want to filter data which is not na's and blanks.

when i try to filter i'm getting datatype mismatch how exactly it works

```
cust.filter((~cust.CODES.isna())|(~cust.CODES==""))

CODES looks some thing like this
----------
ABC43719

EFG43719 EFG437
```

i'm getting this error. i tried isNull() as well

```
AnalysisException: cannot resolve '((`CODES` IS NULL) OR `CODES`)' due to data type mismatch: differing types in '((`CODES` IS NULL) OR `CODES`)' (boolean and string).;;
'Filter NOT ((isnull(CODES#2456) OR CODES#2456) = )

and

'Column' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `isNull`. `isna` is pandas syntax and not usable in pyspark. In the second condition, use `!=`.

```
cust.filter((~cust.CODES.isNull())|(cust.CODES!=""))
```